# How to make loopback 4 application authenticated with keycloak

Tags: node.js, keycloak, loopback, loopback4, keycloak-connect

How to use loopback4 application authentication strategy with keycloak or keycloak-connect .

Keycloak provides steps w.r.t express application but would like to use it in loopback4.

Ref : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_nodejs_adapter

Comment: Keycloak is an OpenID connect compliant authentication and autorisation server. So I think you should rather look in loopback documentation how to integrate with a standard OpenID connect server. However see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#other-openid-connect-libraries for integrating Keycloak without using the provided adapters.

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#validating-access-tokens, with userinfo i checked and updated but need the nodejs adapter like mechanism in loopback Fabrice G. Can u help with this in a sample pet project ?

Answer (score 0):

keycloak-backend npm library provides token verification methods(online and offline) for authentication alone. Offline method requires a public key which can be, in most cases, retrieved from https://{keycloak-domain}/auth/realms/{realm}.